# Plot csv file taking the first column as x axis and the others as y axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a csv file which contains 27 columns. I would take the first column as x axis and rest of them as y axis. I then tried with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
filecsv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Standard\Documents\Code\name.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[plt.plot(filecsv[0],filecsv[x]) for x in range(1,len(filecsv[:,0]))]
```

but I obtained the following error:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: Hi, you should provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help answer the question. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use `filecsv.plot(x=[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native pandas plot: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

The code will be as simple as Quang Hoang suggests: `filecsv.plot(x=[0])`