# Plot csv file taking the first column as x axis and the others as y axis once more

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Can you please elaborate more how to use the solution of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590646/plot-csv-file-taking-the-first-column-as-x-axis-and-the-others-as-y-axis) once more? I have the same problem, I want to use the first column as the x axis and the following columns as y axis values. My code currently looks like this.
But basically I want to have it look like a scatter plot, with the values on each x value.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(
        "ORBGRAND_Hamming_4LWmax_63storeLWsuccess", sep=", ")

    [plt.plot(data[0], data[x]) for x in range(1, len(filecsv[:, 0]))]
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.suptitle("(63,45) BCH", fontsize=40)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.legend(loc='lower left')
    plt.xlabel('$E_b/N_0$ (dB)', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel('BLER', fontsize=20)
    plt.legend(loc='lower left', prop={'size': 17})

plt.show()
```

My file looks like this:

0.000000, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1

0.500000, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1

1.000000, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1

1.500000, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0

2.000000, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0

2.500000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1

3.000000, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0

3.500000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0

4.000000, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0

4.500000, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

5.000000, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0

5.500000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

6.000000, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

I get the following error:

```
Expected 85 fields in line 3, saw 88. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot csv file taking the first column as x axis and the others as y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590646/plot-csv-file-taking-the-first-column-as-x-axis-and-the-others-as-y-axis)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't know how to abstract it to my problem. Where am I supposed to put `filecsv.plot(x=[0])` in the python code?

Comment: @johnny_b_good - As per your question here, you are looking for a scatter plot. The link you provided doesn't appear to be for a scatter plot. Also, the question above appears to be a data error. Please elaborate on the ask. Scatter plot or line plot? The data presented above will not give you error you have mentioned. Will you be providing all 85 lines?

Answer (score 1):

This creates a scatter plot with the first column as x against all the following columns.
As commented above, your error is not from the plotting itself.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This is just a subset of your posted data
data = [[0.000000, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
[0.500000, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
[1.000000, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1.500000, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[2.000000, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# build the dataframe
column_names = [f'y{i}' for i in range(1, len(data[0]))]
column_names[0] = "x"
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["x"] + column_names)

# You didn't specify what plot, I assumed you want all in one figure?
# This plots all the values (y) to the same x colum

plt.figure()
for y in column_names:
    plt.scatter(df["x"], df[y], label=y)
plt.legend()
# Add your aesthetics here
```